# JPA Cast BigDecimal as string

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using JPA to query a database, but something strange happens. In some cases the cast works and compiles fine, but with a BigDecimal it doesn't let me use the cast to make a LIKE with a String. Here is a part of the code that works:

```
"AND cast(pe.pesoObjetivo as string) LIKE :pesoObjetivo% "
```

pesoObjetivo is a data type Double

```
@Column(name = "peso_objetivo")
    private Double pesoObjetivo;
```

But when I try to perform the query with

```
"AND cast(pe.pesoPregestacional) LIKE :pesoPregestacional% " +
```

pesoPregestacional being a BigDecimal

```
 @Column(name = "peso_pregestacional", precision = 21, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal pesoPregestacional;
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 701
```

And the rest of my query
How could I, inside JPA, do a LIKE operation of the BigDecimal data with a String? Or what is my mistake?
By commenting out this line of code or by using

```
"AND pe.pesoPregestacional = :pesoPregestacional% " +
```

Everything works correctly, it's just not what I want. So clearly the error is in this sentence

Comment: Like with a numeric data type always feels a bit strange. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: In order to make a filter from the FrontEnd, if you pass an empty string, it will not be taken into account, but if you write a value, it will look for its corresponding value in the table with the same data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed as string:

Wrong

```
"AND cast(pe.pesoPregestacional) LIKE :pesoPregestacional% " +
```

Correct

```
"AND cast(pe.pesoPregestacional as string) LIKE :pesoPregestacional% " +
```

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize I was missing that sentence. Thank you very much!